# ng-binding data not picking up second selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

**Introduction**

Currently I have a multi selection box, second selection is populated via the first selection.

The second option is not correctly being printed out.

For example I selects `product 1`, then `format 2` I would expect to see

```
{"ProductSelected":{"Pname":"product 1","format":[{"Fname":"format 2","id":"2"}
```

but the model is printing all the formats linked to the product

```
{"ProductSelected":{"Pname":"product 1","format":[{"Fname":"format 1","id":"1"},{"Fname":"format 2","id":"2"}]},"format":"2"}
```

**Question**

why is it printing all formats linked to the product and how do i fix my code to only print the format selected ?

**My selection boxes HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div ng-controller="dropDown">
        <select ng-model="formData.ProductSelected"
                ng-options="product.Pname for product in productsandformats">
            <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="formData.format"
                ng-options="format.id as format.Fname for format in formData.ProductSelected.format"
                ng-if="formData.ProductSelected">
            <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My controller code js**

```
FirstModule.controller('dropDown', function ($scope) {

        $scope.productsandformats = [
            {
                "Pname": "product 1",
                "format": [
                    {"Fname": "format 1", "id": "1"},
                    {"Fname": "format 2", "id": "2"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "Pname": "product 2",
                "format": [
                    {"Fname": "format 3", "id": "3"},
                    {"Fname": "format 2", "id": "2"},
                    {"Fname": "format 4", "id": "4"},
                    {"Fname": "format 5", "id": "5"}
                ]
            }];

        $scope.user = {productName: $scope.productsandformats[0]};

        $scope.displayModalValue = function () {
            console.log($scope.user.productName);
        }

    })
```

Comment: i think your json format is incorrect for your condition.

Comment: @SangramBadi ok ill look into it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly here's why: [PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/KmOyxW). Basically, you can't make the source of data your destination, as your data will just get corrupted. What you can do is to make shallow copy of formats, and use it to make options you need: [WORKING PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/KmOyrW)

```
$scope.formats = {};
$scope.productsandformats.forEach(pf=>{
    $scope.formats[pf.Pname] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pf.format));
})
```

Comment: Hmm, not perfect but it may work. ill play with this try and get this working on my local and accept, thanks.

Comment: Ill keep looking at this but i can seem to get it working. ill keep trying